# Cannot import anything from sklearn.ensemble

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.ensemble._forest import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
```

when I try to import anything from ensemble, there's always error like:

[image: traceback]

I tried

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn
```

Comment: That's wacky.  Could you go to that local file (`...site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py`) and provide a few lines of context?  `class 2,2` is indeed invalid syntax, and it's hard to understand how it could have come to be there...

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix conda with pip.

Try these steps:

1. `pip uninstall sklearn`  and then `pip install -U scikit-learn`
2. Replace

   ```
   from sklearn.ensemble._forest import VotingClassifier
   ```

   with

   ```
   from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
   ```